# Made a weird typo doing a redirect, and the result baffles me

Tags: redirect

I'm learning bash, and was doing some simple redirect exercises.

Intended to type: `echo "hello world" > file1` ; easy-peasy, creates a file called "file1" with the text "hello world".

Accidentally typed: `echo "hello world" > file 1`, with a space between "file" and "1".

The result was a new file called "file" (makes sense), but the text in the file was "hello world 1".

Question: How on earth did my misplaced 1 get appended to the text in the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "hello world" > file 1
```

command is the same as

```
echo "hello world" 1 > file
```

It doesn't matter where the `>` is.

Comment: However, space between `1` and `>` is meaningful; `echo "hello world" 1 > file` would give a different result than `echo "hello world" 1> file` (the latter is just equivalent to `echo "hello world" > file`)

Comment: `1>` has another meaning. It redirects only standard output.

Comment: Thank you! Played around with putting the redirect in different places (even right after echo), and indeed it doesn't matter.  Sort of counterintuitive, since I thought the order mattered (ie stuff_before_redirect goes to redirect_place).  Is there an underlying principle I can take away from this?

Comment: You can read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html First redirection is done, then the command executed.

Comment: @Pilot6 `1>` is exactly the same as `>`. Both redirect only standard output. If you want to redirect stderr, you have to use `2>` or (in bash) `>&`.